# Can we reopen question 9506 (How to pitch a message for a Fraternity Election)?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request

Currently, this question: [How do I pitch a message for a Fraternity Election?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/9506/1599) is only one reopen vote away from being reopened.

The OP answered all the questions for clarification and edited their question accordingly.

Is there anything still missing, that makes it so no-one casts that last reopen vote? Is there now something else wrong with the question?

Could someone please leave feedback for the OP on what else to improve? (or reopen)

Comment: Done. Now voted and reopened @Tinkeringbell.